# JavaScript/TypeScript Code Duplication (JSCPD) Ignore Imports

Tags: javascript, typescript, cpd

*Some background:* I am developing two main projects. The first project is an API written in TypeScript using NodeJS. The second project is also written in TypeScript, using Ionic Framework to develop a hybrid mobile application.

I recently added `jscpd` to my project to detect duplicate blocks of code. It works very well except for one primary issue: it detects **import** statements as code duplications.

**My question:** How do I force `jscpd` to ignore all import statements in my code?

The documentation for jscpd is quite lousy and there seems to be no answers online. I could only find one resource that addresses this issue (on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/kucherenko/jscpd/issues/341)), and the project maintainer just dismissed the issue rather than providing an actual solution.

Below is my config file:

**.jscpd.json**

```json
{
    "path": ["src/"],
    "output": "cpd",
    "reporters": ["console", "html"],
    "minLines": 2,
    "minTokens": 10,
    "blame": true,
    "threshold": 0.1,
    "languages": ["typescript"],
    "ignore": ["import .*"]
}
```

My script to run `jscpd` is:

```bash
jscpd --config .jscpd.json   # Execute jscpd
open ./cpd/html/index.html   # Open the results in the browser
```